# The Riemann-Roch Theorem for line bundles on a regular projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

This is exercise 18.4.B in Vakil's FOAG.

> Suppose $D$ is a divisor on a regular projective curve $C$ over a field $k$. Show that $\lambda(C,\mathcal{O}_C(D)) = \mathrm{deg} D + \lambda(C,\mathcal{O}_C)$

As said in the hint, an essential step is to tensor the closed subscheme exact sequence
$$ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_C(-p) \to \mathcal{O}_C\to \mathcal{O}|_p \to 0 $$
by $\mathcal{O}_C(D)$. For the new short sequence to be exact, we need $\mathcal{O}_C(D)$ to be a line bundle, so that $- \otimes \mathcal{O}_C(D)$ is exact.

But I can't see $\mathcal{O}_C(D)$  is a line bundle, any hint is welcome.

**Edit**: We define $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ by

$\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X(D)):= \{t\in K(X)^{\times} :div|_U t +D|_U \ge0 \} \cup \{ 0\}$

and define $\mathrm{deg} D = \Sigma  a_p \mathrm{deg}  p$, where $\mathrm{deg}p$ is the degree of the field extension of the residue field over $k$.

Comment: All you need to do is (since $C$ is a curve) show that $O_C(D)$ is finitely generated, torsion-free, and that its stalk at the generic point is $k(C)$.

Comment: A good place to start would be with Vakil's definition of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$. Could you add it to your post with an [edit], please?

Comment: @KReiser OK, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Have you tried to solve exercise 14.3.I in FOAG?

Comment: @danneks Yes, it seems that it could be applied directly to this problem.